# Checked All Child Issue

Tags: android, checkbox, hashmap, android-recyclerview

Actually I am not getting size when I am printing Toast in checked-box Checked Event in android.

Here is my Code on parent checkbox in android if I will get the size the problem will automatically solved.

This code is declared in custom Adapter.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Key: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String val = allCityList.get(position);
    Integer cnt = val.split("-").length;

    if (cnt > 1) {
        val = val.split("-")[1];
        holder.chkbox_parent.setText(val);
        holder.chkbox_parent.setTag("State");
        holder.chkbox_parent.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        stateTag = val;
    } else {
        val = val.split("-")[0];
        holder.chkbox_parent.setText(val);
        holder.chkbox_parent.setTag(stateTag);
    }

holder.chkbox_parent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) holder.chkbox_parent;

            if (chk.getTag().equals("State")) {
                String state = chk.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    RecyclerView rv1 = holder.rvParent;
//                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+rv1.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rv1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        Log.e("hello......", ""+rv1.getChildCount());
                        CheckBox cb;
                        cb = (CheckBox) rv1.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.chkbox_parent);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "" + cb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 //                if (state.equals(cb.getTag()))
//                    cb.setChecked(chk.isChecked());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Issue is **coming on recyclerview ie rv.getchildcount**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, invoking `getChildCount()` will return only visible items at the moment. RecyclerView is subclass of ViewGroup which provides such method and is not designed to access child views directly. You should try to move checking/unchecking/accessing state logic to your `Adapter` and use `notifyDatasetChanged()` and `notifyItemChanged(int position)` to inform adapter that something happened.

Comment: Can you please elaborate I understand Few thing or Can you show me a demo Program.

Comment: I only presented violations of RecyclerView API you made. I assumed, that getting children count is not what you wanted (common mistake) and what you really want to do is to get/set some particular items state. To be honest, you don't seem to fully understand how RecyclerView works and without you knowing some basic concepts it'll be hard for me to explain everything step by step. You should try to go through one of RecyclerView tutorials, like this one: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/). It'll help you to understand recycling concept.

Comment: I guess you are right but what i had shown in my code is when we checked the checkbox all sub checkbox to be selected(select all)Do you have any soln regarding that?

Comment: If you want an interaction with any other items within the same RecyclerView, you should use adapter as a proxy. You should make your adapter to be the only part that is keeping `state` and separate it from presentation layer (`onBindViewHolder`). For example, if you have number of checkboxes inside RV keep their state in separate collection and update UI using this state. Don't touch CheckBoxes from outside onBindViewHolder (not event OnClickListeners)

Comment: I got it Thank you Mr Quattro.

Comment: And I had done it Thank you :) for your guidence it was quite useful for me